# Diagnosing routing lags on OpenWRT

Tags: linux, router, routing, openwrt

I have a GL-MT300A router which comes with OpenWRT by default. In the setup I'm using, the GL-MT300A is connected with a cable to a ISP provided router. Through this the GL-MT300A server as an NATed access point allowing me to have a wifi network I can manage how i want.

I have started experiencing very long lags when browsing the Internet through the GL-MT300A provided wifi.

To diagnose the problem I have:

- connected to the ISP router with the cable (no delay)
- connected to the GL-MT300A admin page, same subnet (no delay)

Base on that I'm assuming that the issues as something to do with how the routing is happening inside the GL-MT300A.

Is there a utility or an approach for OpenWRT or Linux generally, that can help me with measuring the latencies and diagnosing the problem deeper?

Comment: @acejavelin You're right, my bad, will correct immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already gone through the steps to enable Smart Queue Management (FQ-CoDel) and combat bufferbloat, you should do that first.

You can follow [OpenWrt's anti-bufferbloat HowTo](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/sqm).

Comment: While installing SQM it's probably a useful piece of advice, it doesn't really answer the title question: how to *diagnose* the latency?
I would, at least, include a link to SQM diagnostics wiki page: https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/Tests_for_Bufferbloat/

Comment: @VictorSergienko He had already described classic bufferbloat. I just had to let him know that that's exactly what he'd described, and that SQM was the solution. In the very unlikely chance it was wrong, enabling SQM to rule out bufferbloat would have been the most important diagnostic next step.